# Egrep expression as a grep expression

Tags: terminal, grep, file-search

I have this egrep command which's expression searchs for filenames with length 3 (excluding .extension):

```
ls | grep -E '^.{3}\.+'
```

However, I'm unable to write this with grep only, is it possible?

Comment: Why `grep`, why not `ls ???.*`?

Comment: That should work.  Note though, that the "+" is not needed (asks for 1 or more periods at the end, but can be followed by anything).  Also - @1_CR's answer makes a lot more sense...

Comment: I know I know @1_CR , I just really want to know how to do it with grep, curiosity..

Comment: The BRE equivalent would be `grep '^.\{3\}\.\+'` I think (i.e. escape the braces and the +)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ls | grep '^.\{3\}\.\+'
```

> Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions
>
> In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions \?, +, {, \|, (, and ).

(from `man grep`)

(I can see that steeldriver beat me to it by some 30s while I was formulating the answer.)